# How to implement Angular/Ionic 7 sheet modal bottom gap

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

Is there a way to add a gap between the bottom of the ionic 'sheet' modal and the screen?

I expect this behaviour:
[image: expected behaviour]

This is how far I have gotten (ignore the design differences):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmunhj?file=src%2Fglobal.css

I have read the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal) and found nothing useful, and I couldn't hack my way around it.
Should I submit a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted [an issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/28191). Turns out the solution already exists, I just weren't aware of it. I quote:

"You can achieve this by setting the margin on the content Shadow Part: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ymkck5 "

Answer (score 1):

> Should I submit a feature request?

No The bottom sheet modal is working as intended. Ionic will deem this not a feature, but a user enhancement. So it's up to you to add the styles to it.

the Modal is using shadow dom, so good luck trying to add that bottom space!

PS: you shouldn't be adding that bottom space anyway. That space is intended for other features for devices such as bringin the multitask bar for ios. you're opening the possibility for users to have UI issues within your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the constructive comments, hence I gave it an upvote, however I'd like to specify that our designer in our team specifically designed the modal to have a bottom margin, and - to my knowledge - it does not cause UI issues on IOS or Android.

Comment: Sounds like the designed does not know the common UI/UX specs, if it's too close to the bottom safe area, it can be. Thank you for the upvote!